# Why is Mule HTTP PollingConnector returning 403 Forbidden Error when trying to read some RSS feeds

Tags: rss, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to pull an RSS feed with Mule Studio. I can view this feed in the browser using an RSS feeder and using CURL but I can't do it with the Mule application. This Mule application works with other RSS feeds so I don't understand why I would be receiving a 403 Forbidden error for this feed.

This is my Mule flow XML

```
<http:polling-connector name="PollingHttpConnector" pollingFrequency="60000" doc:name="HTTP Polling" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape"  receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true"/>
<flow name="mondavi" doc:name="mondavi">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"   doc:name=" " address="http://www.theaggie.org/feed/" connector-ref="PollingHttpConnector" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <logger message=" #[header:INBOUND:http.version] #[header:INBOUND:http.method] #[header:INBOUND:http.request]   " level="INFO" category="mule.http.accesslog" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <component class="edu.ucdavis.edustream.esb.news.rss.OrigFeedSplitter" doc:name="Java"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <component class="edu.ucdavis.edustream.esb.news.rss.EntryReceiver" doc:name="Java"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${edus.host}" port="${edus.port}" path="api/v1/activity" method="POST" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Here is the response from the successful CURL request, only requesting the header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 19:06:51 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=l0eg8e93ihb3r65plms64l84f7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://www.theaggie.org/xmlrpc.php
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 03:37:00 GMT
ETag: "556af474b6fdedb235c46e19926f69db"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.theaggie.org/feed/ rejects HTTP GETs when the user agent is "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1", which is what Mule uses.

```
$ curl -I -H "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" http://www.theaggie.org/feed/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 19:27:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Status: 403 Forbidden
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I would be able to change the User-Agent on Mule in order to be able to receive the feed?

Comment: Ahem, it's supposed to be a bad practice to cheat about your user agent... Ideally we should ask these guys to stop sucking. In a less ideal world, I could tell you that you can simply use `http://www.theaggie.org/feed/?User-Agent=MuleESB` as the endpoint address and it will work. But again, that would be bad practice :)